# Create a pivot table for m-n relationship in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, table, spatial-relationship

My dataset comprises many polygons representing workspaces over a large area:

-1 vector layer comprising my polygons (each polygon ID appears 1 time)

For my online atlas however I need to obtain a pivot table layer as follows :

-1 pivot table listing all the polygon couples less than 300 meters apart (each polygon ID appears over more than 1 line depending the nb neighbor polygons).
I have no clue how to obtain this in QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with SQL, you can make a virtual layer based on following reason: If you buffer each polygon with 300 meters, you can do an intersect to couple all neigbouring polygons within a given distance.

in code this gives:

```
    select
    a.geometry,
    a.id,
    b.id
    from polygonlayer a, polygonlayer b
    where st_intersects(a.geometry, st_buffer(b.geometry, 300)) and a.id != b.id
```

Put this code in a virtual layer (layer > add layer > add virtual layer) and check 'autodetect'.

[image]

This gives following result:

[image]

You can use that table as coverage layer in the print composer.

Comment: Thanks ! Small question, Is there any way to save the data in this layer non-virtually ? I need to add a few things manually and use it to create relationships in lizmap.

Comment: Yes, you can save this result (right-click and choose save as...) in whatever format you want.